What formula would I use to calculate total income over $x$ years with a fixed salary increase rate.
I'm wanting to calculate how much total money I would have earned over x amount of years, but while accounting for increase in pay at the end of each year (or maybe even continuous?)
Lets say for instance I start by making 100,000 a year. So obviously the formula would be income $= 100,000X$. But if my job gave me a say $3\%$ raise increase each year, that would change this formula.
Does anyone know how I would write a formula to calculate this?
I was first thinking this would simply be something like $(1.03)^x * 100000 * x\ldots$ But I realized that would be the formula for calculating what you would make if over $x$ years you had the salary at $x$ years for each of those years, so obviously that would be much higher than what I'm trying to calculate.

Simply add the years together. You can do this using a sum formula.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N} p^{k} \cdot s_0$$
N is the years you've worked there ($N = 0$ being the first year), $p$ the yearly salary increase (in your case $1.03$) and $s_0$ your starting salary (in your case $100 \ 000$)
This can be rewritten to
$$  s_0\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{N} p^{k}$$
and then, using an identity,
$$  s_0\cdot \frac{1-p^{N+1}}{1-p}$$

Lets say the starting salary is $S$, the yearly increase is positive $r\%$, and you want to calculate over $x$ years (for simplicity we consider $x$ as an integer)
Then the total salary you get as a function of $x$ is: $$f(x) = S + \left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)S + \left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^2 S + \dots + \left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^{x-1}S$$
Multiplying L.H.S and R.H.S by $\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)$:
$$\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right) f(x) = \left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)S + \left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^2 S + \dots + \left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^xS $$
Subtracting the above two equations, majority of the terms cancel out:
$$\begin{split}
\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right) f(x) - f(x) &= \left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^xS - S \\
f(x) &= S\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^x - 1}{\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right) - 1}\right)
\end{split}$$
